# python plotly\dash - draw data with image in background

Tags: python, plotly-dash

In the plotly [manual](https://plotly.com/python/imshow/#combining-image-charts-and-other-traces) there is some example on this. However, there is no info on same issue while using the dash.

I've tried following this example and create my own example, I don't see the image

```
img = plt.imread('link1.png')

app.layout = html.Div([
    # auto update every 60 msec
    dcc.Interval(id='graph-update', interval=5000),
    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            html.H3("Bearing-Depression", style={'text-align': 'center'}),
            dcc.Graph(id='f1', figure={})],
            className="six columns"),
    ],
    className="row"),
])

@ app.callback([Output('f1', 'figure'),],
           [Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals')])
def update(n):
    fig2 = px.imshow((img), origin='lower')
    
    fig2.update_xaxes(tickvals=[0, 30, 60, 90, 120,
                            150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360])
    fig2.update_yaxes(tickvals=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70,
                            80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180])
    data = df[df.condition == "OK"]
    fig2.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data['x'],
                          y=data['y'],
                          marker=dict(color='black', symbol='circle'),
                          name="OK"
                          ))
    return fig2
```

Any suggestion what could be done so that I'll have an image and a scatter plot on same figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to refer to a local in an image reference on Dash, you need to convert it to base64 format. The code I've provided will probably need to be adjusted in size and position to fit your graph. Officially, I referred to [this](https://plotly.com/python/images/).You may also find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65453880/create-background-image-for-a-plot-using-plotly-dash/65454472#65454472) helpful.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import base64

# img = plt.imread('link1.png')
img = base64.b64encode(open('link1.png', 'rb').read())

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    # auto update every 60 msec
    dcc.Interval(id='graph-update', interval=5000),
    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            html.H3("Bearing-Depression", style={'text-align': 'center'}),
            dcc.Graph(id='f1', figure={})],
            className="six columns"),
    ],
    className="row"),
])

@ app.callback([Output('f1', 'figure'),],
           [Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals')])
def update(n):
    fig2 = px.imshow((img), origin='lower')
    
    fig2.update_xaxes(tickvals=[0, 30, 60, 90, 120,
                            150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360])
    fig2.update_yaxes(tickvals=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70,
                            80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180])
    data = df[df.condition == "OK"]
    fig2.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data['x'],
                          y=data['y'],
                          marker=dict(color='black', symbol='circle'),
                          name="OK"
                          ))
    fig2.add_layout_image(dict(source='data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(img.decode()),
                               xref="x", 
                               yref="y",
                               x=0,
                               y=3,
                               sizex=2,
                               sizey=2,
                               sizing="stretch",
                               opacity=0.5,
                               layer="below"))
    return fig2

 app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: This was my initial solution, but it didn't worked as I wanted. Eventually found where I was wrong.

Comment: When referring to other questions, be sure to check with the person who asked the question. Please forgive my rudeness.